# smtp сервер не может соединиться с mail.ru?

Tags: email, smtp

Поднял почтовый сервер.

Доставка с mail.ru на него работает правильно письма приходят.
Доставка с клиента на сервер работает правильно,
но при попытке моего smtp сервера соединяться с сервером mail.ru для передачи письма на ящик mail.ru, не может подключиться и пишет:

```
"Starting external delivery process. Server: mxs.mail.ru (94.100.180.150), Port: 25, Security: 2, User name: "
"DEBUG" 2248    "2016-01-26 03:42:36.461"   "Creating session 453"
"TCPIP" 2248    "2016-01-26 03:42:36.461"   "Connecting to 94.100.180.150:25..."
"DEBUG" 1240    "2016-01-26 03:42:57.477"   "SMTPDeliverer - Message 35 - Connection failed: Host name: 94.100.180.150, message: Превышен таймаут семафора"
```

То есть он пытается соединиться по порту 25 и не может. Или с сервера запрос не приходит, или mail.ru блокирует соединение.
Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Первым делом - с помощью `telnet 94.100.180.150 25` на самом сервере проверить, удаётся ли такое соединение. Если нет - изучать конфигурацию локальных и внешних файрволов. Если да - добиваться более подробных логов сервера.

Comment: @Outtruder
Telnet не соединяет. А должен? Вроде как порт 25 у этого ip mail.ru открыт.

Даже если отключить firewall всё равно не соединяет. 
Может быть есть внешний firewall у хостинг провайдера или это невозможно?

Comment: Мне с моего текущего соединения с Интернет подсоединиться на 25 порт этого адреса удаётся. Значит, проблема может быть с вашим провайдером: многие закрывают своим клиентам исходящие соединения на 25 порт в целях борьбы со спамом. В таком случае провайдер обычно предоставляет свой SMTP relay сервер.